# In Java what is the syntax for commenting out multiple lines?

Tags: java, comments

In Java what is the syntax for commenting out multiple lines?

I want to do something like:

```
(comment)
LINES I WANT COMMENTED
LINES I WANT COMMENTED
LINES I WANT COMMENTED
(/comment)
```

Comment: Probably stackoverflow is even faster than google :), google is so 2009.

Comment: +1 There's no community of developers moderating Google links. And you can learn so much more than just what you asked when you come to StackOverflow.

Comment: A helpful tip, if your using jetbrains intelliJ, highlight the lines you want commented and hit CTRL + /

Comment: Yep. In the last seven years I managed to figure that out.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

```
/* 
LINES I WANT COMMENTED 
LINES I WANT COMMENTED 
LINES I WANT COMMENTED 
*/
```

Answer (score 20):

```
/* 
Lines to be commented
*/
```

NB: multiline comments like this DO NOT NEST. This can be the source of errors. It is generally better to just comment every line with //. Most IDEs allow you to do this quite simply.

Comment: ..which is to be done with `Ctrl`+`/` in Eclipse. To uncomment, hit it once again. You dan do it for multiple selected lines.

Comment: Good to know. I don't use it, so I didn't mention about it :)

Comment: This is a better answer, the accepted answer does not handle nesting of `/* */` comments

Answer (score 14):

As @kgrad says, /* */ does not nest and can cause errors. A better answer is:

```
// LINE *of code* I WANT COMMENTED 
// LINE *of code* I WANT COMMENTED 
// LINE *of code* I WANT COMMENTED
```

Most IDEs have a single keyboard command for doing/undoing this, so there's really no reason to use the other style any more. For example: in eclipse, select the block of text and hit Ctrl+/

To undo that type of comment, use Ctrl+\

UPDATE: The [Sun (now Oracle) coding convention](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-comments.html#286) says that this style should not be used for block *text* comments:

```
// Using the slash-slash
// style of comment as shown
// in this paragraph of non-code text is 
// against the coding convention.
```

but // can be used 3 other ways:

1. A single line comment
2. A comment at the end of a line of code
3. Commenting out a block of code

Answer (score 11):

```
/*
 *STUFF HERE
 */
```

or you can use `//` on every line.

Below is what is called a JavaDoc comment which allows you to use certain tags (@return, @param, etc...) for documentation purposes.

```
   /**
    *COMMENTED OUT STUFF HERE
    *AND HERE
    */
```

More information on comments and conventions can be found [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/codeconv/html/CodeConventions.doc4.html).

Comment: That is a JavaDoc entry, not a comment.

Comment: yea did on accident and was fixing while you commented

Comment: The first is a JavaDoc comment yes, the second is a simple block comment. ~fixing again so no one gets confused~

Answer (score 5):

With `/**/`:

```
/*
stuff to comment
*/
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use /* begin comment
and end it with */

Or you can simply use // across each line (not recommended)

```
/*
Here is an article you could of read that tells you all about how to comment
on multiple lines too!:

[http://java.sun.com/docs/codeconv/html/CodeConventions.doc4.html][1]
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

- The simple question to your answer is already answered a lot of times:

  ```
  /*
  LINES I WANT COMMENTED
  LINES I WANT COMMENTED
  LINES I WANT COMMENTED
  */
  ```
- From your question it sounds like you want to comment out a lot of code?? I would advise to use a [repository(git/github)](http://help.github.com/) to manage your files instead of commenting out lines.
- My last advice would be to learn about [javadoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javadoc) if not already familiar because documenting your code is really important.